# Swift 2 - create empty array of UITableVIewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a subclass of `UITableViewController` in which I defined

```
var allCells: [UITableViewCell]
```

But it gives me the error

> Stored property 'allCells' without initial value prevents synthesized
>   initializers

And it suggests me to change the definition to

```
var allCells: [UITableViewCell] = []
```

But the "fix" doesn't work neither, because it fails with this

> Class '...' has no initializers

How can I define a variable that will be an `array` of `UITableViewCell`

---

**UPDATE**

Here is what my class looks like

```
class MyClass: UITableViewController, SomeDelegate {



    @IBAction func cancelAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.delegate?.closeScreen()
    }




    var delegate: SomeDelegate?
    var newUser = NewUser()

    var datePickerCell: UITableViewCell
    var allCells: [UITableViewCell]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        allCells = [
            self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("....")!,
            self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("....")!,
            self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("....")!
        ]

        datePickerCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DPCell")!

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);


        initStyles()


    }

    .....

}
```

Comment: The second line is correct. Something else must be wrong. Can you show more contextual code?

Comment: Actually the second one is correct. Show us the rest of your code...
Or try this: var allCells: [UITableViewCell]? = []  
Although it doesn't make really sense because it should work without "?" And it isn't optional because it is empty...

Comment: You probably have some more properties that are not correctly initialized, show more code. The error message has nothing to do with the one you show right now.

Comment: I have updated the post with more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
   var datePickerCell: UITableViewCell!
   var allCells: [UITableViewCell]()
```

Comment: Still the same error - Class '...' has no initializers

Comment: @Stevik as to be expected since what you have shown is perfectly fine, provide more code.

Comment: post more of your code then. something else must be wrong.

Comment: @joey thanks, you're a life saver, it works!
I have tried also var allCells: [UITableViewCell] = [] which works as well, so then which one is better ?

Comment: it depends on what you want. As far as I know (and I'm no expert--only 267 reputation myself, lol), saying  var allCells: [UITableViewCell] = [] is making a new empty array of uitableviewcells. That means the array exists and you can call methods on it (like allCells.count) and it will return the value--because it exists, but just has 0 values in it. Saying var allCells= [UITableViewCell]() is initializing a new array, but it has no values yet. It isn't empty, but its contents aren't full either--the array is just waiting to be used. That's my understanding. Maybe someone else will know better

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
var allCells = [UITableViewCell]()
```

and let the compiler infer the type.

Also, that is probably a bad idea, as that's not supposed to be needed for `UITableView`s. But there you go, just in case you have a valid reason to store that.

**Edit**:
As the compiler already tells you,

```
var allCells : [UITableViewCell]
```

only defines `allCells`' type without initializing. The correct initializer for an array of `UITableViewCell` is `[UITableViewCell]()`.